# How to detect event when chrome packaged app uninstalled?

Tags: google-chrome, event-handling, google-chrome-app, uninstallation

I am developing a chrome packaged app. As part of the app i need to know, when user uninstalled the app. I could not find any method as part of the API,to read such a event when it happens. In extensions we have chrome.management api to do this, but chrome packaged app doesn't have this permission. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-setUninstallURL), this allows you to set a URL which is loaded as soon as the App is removed from Chrome. It does not require any additional permissions.

Comment: Yes, When i get the gcm registration success callback, i set uninstall url. When ever user uninstall the app, it opens uninstall url in a tab. And this is used to notify my server to remove registration record from my db.  Is there any other way to know at client when it happens?